# Issue with initalizing moonpay sdk for androind in a flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, sdk

so i have tried to follow along this documentation to initalize the moonpay sdk for android, so i have tried to initalize it in android/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt (is that the right place?)
link for documentation: [https://dev.moonpay.com/docs/ramps-sdk-install-android](https://stackoverflow.com)

so when i try to run my project (flutter run)

i get this error:

```
e: /home/hansailo/Development/Sirience-Mobile/android/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt: (53, 72): Type mismatch: inferred type is MainActivity but ComponentActivity was expected
e: /home/hansailo/Development/Sirience-Mobile/android/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt: (55, 17): Unresolved reference: MoonPayRenderingOptionAndroid

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             41.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and its weird because i have followed the documentation, expect the url signing because i already have the wallet address in the ui.

here is my code in MainActivity.kt:

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import com.moonpay.sdk.MoonPayAndroidSdk
import com.moonpay.sdk.MoonPaySdkBuyConfig
import com.moonpay.sdk.MoonPayWidgetEnvironment
import com.moonpay.sdk.MoonPayBuyQueryParams
import com.moonpay.sdk.MoonPayHandlers
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "...../moonpay"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                if (call.method == "startMoonPay") {
                    initMoonPay()
                }
            }
    }

    private fun initMoonPay() {
      val handlers = MoonPayHandlers(
  onSwapsCustomerSetupComplete = {
    Log.i("HANDLER CALLED","onSwapsCustomerSetupComplete called!")
    },
  onAuthToken = {
    Log.i("HANDLER CALLED", "onAuthToken called with payload $it")
    },
  onLogin = {
    Log.i("HANDLER CALLED", "onLogin called with payload $it")
    },
  onKmsWalletCreated = {
    Log.i("HANDLER CALLED", "onKmsWalletCreated called!")
    },
)

        val params = MoonPayBuyQueryParams("MOONPAY_API_KEY")
        params.setCurrencyCode("USDT")

        val config = MoonPaySdkBuyConfig(
            environment = MoonPayWidgetEnvironment.Sandbox,
            debug = true,
            params = params,
            handlers = handlers
        )

        val moonPaySdk = MoonPayAndroidSdk(config = config, activity = this)

moonPaySdk.show(MoonPayRenderingOptionAndroid.InAppBrowser())

    }
}
```

the error are comming from these lines:
`val moonPaySdk = MoonPayAndroidSdk(config = config, activity = this) moonPaySdk.show(MoonPayRenderingOptionAndroid.InAppBrowser())`

- so i have updated minumum sdk version in build.gradle from 21 to 28
- had to download cmdline-tools in Android/Sdk again and accept new licenses
- asked chatgpt but it was to little help